# Get name of object clicked

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a bunch of Tcubes made at runtime inside a viewport3D.  I would like to know if one is clicked on.  and if so return the name of this TCube.

small example of what i am talking about.

```
procedure blockClicked;
begin
  //get name of block
  //checkMode ( add , delete, other)
  //get name of block x, y, and z
  //do other stuff
end;
```

Comment: What about just assigning a common [`OnClick`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Types3D.TControl3D.OnClick) event for all those `TCube` objects and accessing the clicked one's object by typecasting the `Sender` parameter like `TCube(Sender)...` ?

Comment: @TLama  sounds like it would work.. but got a basic set up of how?

Comment: i added an answer, does that look right? i am only guessing?

Comment: I don't know how are you creating your objects but basically you need to make e.g. a private method which matches the prototype of the event method. In this case to the `TNotifyEvent`. In code this may look [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/vf7ffiaB) (according to your previous question about array). The same you would do in VCL application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.cubeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Cube: TCube;
begin
  // Senders points to the cube clicked
  cube := Sender as Tcube; 
end;
```

Comment: You want the name, don't you? So that property is still missing in your code. Try using `(Sender as TCube).Name` somewhere...

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Anyway, if you are sure that the `CubeClick` method will be assigned always only to the `TCube` objects, you may use direct typecast by `Cube := TCube(Sender);`. The `as` operator (`Sender as TCube`) is safer in that it *tries to typecast* object to the desired type and if that's not possible, it raises an exception about it, whilst with direct typecasting (`TCube(Sender)`) you're expecting just the object (`Sender`) will be of that desired type (but it's bad if it's not of that type).

Comment: Thanks going to try it and see what happens :D

Comment: @Sherlock70, it's better to store that object reference to a local variable if you're going to access that object more than once (in the question represented by the comment *get name of block x, y and z*). Now the OP can access the object properties in the way like `Cube.Name, Cube.Position.X` etc.

Comment: @TLama Using the `as` cast is in effect a runtime assertion that you got the code right. It doesn't cost any discernible time to perform that test since UI clicks are never a CPU bottleneck. I would always use `as` in this scenario.